# MongoDB $group where value is no null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that stores transcript in this format:

```
{
 convId: abcd,
 timestamp: 2020-02-08T15:43,
 source: { channel: 'channel1' }
},
{
 convId: abcd,
 timestamp: 2020-02-08T15:42,
 source: { channel: 'channel1' }
},
{
 convId: abcd,
 timestamp: 2020-02-08T15:41,
 source: { channel: null }
},
```

Some of the records has source.channel field empty. When I use aggregation pipeline to get unique conversations for some of them, I get source.channel as *null*, which is a problem. I am using below 
$group stage:

```
$group: {
 _id: '$convId',
 started: { $min: '$timestamp' },
 ended: { $max: '$timestamp' },
 channel: { $first: '$source.channel' },
}
```

I know this is a problem because of $first, so I tried using $min and $max (along with other aggregation operators) as they supposed to ignore null values, but it won't for unknown reasons (at least 1 document has source.channel field populated with not null).

Can anyone suggest how I could exclude *null* and return field with a value?

Edit: I need all documents for timestamps so I can't refine that in $match.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the variable for null value, and if it is not null you can return the value else null.

```
$group: {
 _id: '$convId',
 started: { $min: '$timestamp' },
 ended: { $max: '$timestamp' },
 channel: { $cond: {
if: {
$ne: [ "$source.channel", null ]
}, then: "$source.channel", else: 'your_value'
} },
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. However, the 'channel' value is dynamic, thus I would need to set 'else'  with the value of document where it's not null. Is it possible?